# How to supply an equals/hash function to JS Array.includes()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, contains, equality, predicate

Is there a way to get [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to also work with non-primitive objects by supplying a equals+hash predicate?

For example given a list:

```js
var list = [{id:111},{id:222},{id:333}];

console.log(list.includes({id:333});
// output: false
```

From the above example it looks like equality is done by object identity (i.e. memory address) and not by value which makes, of course, total sense and is expected. But is there a way to supply an equality function to `list.includes()` so that the primitive value of `id` is used to determine equality?

The [Arrays.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) documentation does not mention anything about accepting an equality predicate.

Comment: Duplicate of [check if an array “includes” an item in Javascript](/q/55414938/4642212).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) takes two parameters:

> searchElement: The value to search for.

> fromIndex (Optional): The position in this array at which to begin searching for searchElement.

You can use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead:

```js
const list = [{id:111},{id:222},{id:333}];

console.log( list.some(({id}) => id === 333) );
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! It's unexpected though that a separate method `some()` was introduced rather than having `includes()` accept an optional predicate; to me, logically, `some()` is the same as `includes()`.

Comment: @ccpizza `includes` searches for the specified value; you wouldn’t want to create separate functions for each value; but you should be able to search for function objects as well.

Comment: ``Array#includes`` uses the ``sameValueZero`` algorithm to determine whether an element is found. You can read more about it. ``Array#some`` tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function